# Moq callback caching stale variable value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have this sample code snippet below.
The Test_MailIt test method fails with the error

> 'Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<7>. '

I would expect it to pass because I'd expect the `testMailItem` to be `0` the first time `ReusableMethod` is called, and `7` the second time `ReusableMethod` is called.

However it seems that the callback has somehow cached `testMailItem` value from the first time it was called.

```
public interface IMyWebSocket
{
    public void send(int a);
}

public class PostMan
{
    IMyWebSocket socket;

    public PostMan(IMyWebSocket _socket)
    {
        this.socket = _socket;
    }

    public void MailIt(int mailItem)
    {
        this.socket.send(mailItem);
    }
}
```

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_MailIt()
    {
        int testMailItem = 0;
        PostMan p = ReusableMethod(testMailItem, null);

        testMailItem = 7;
        PostMan p1 = ReusableMethod(testMailItem, p);

    }

    private PostMan ReusableMethod(int testMailItem, PostMan p=null )
    {
        if (p==null)
        {
            Mock<IMyWebSocket> obj = new Mock<IMyWebSocket>();
            obj.Setup(x => x.send(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<int>((x) => { Assert.AreEqual(testMailItem, x); });
            p = new PostMan(obj.Object);
        }

        p.MailIt(testMailItem);
        return p;      
    }
}
```

Is this behavior expected ? The aim here is not to refactor to get this to work, but to understand why the callback is unable to use `testMailItem` as passed to `ReusableMethod` the second time.

Comment: Use standard explicit `Arrange - Act - Assert` approach.

Comment: What do you want to test here? What do you verify with this test case?

Comment: @PeterCsala  my aim is to essentially test the values of the parameters passed to the send method

Comment: Have you tried to use Capture.In feature of moq?

Comment: I will explore Capture.In, but for now I was able to get unblocked by, passing in a shared object containing the value, then modifying the shared object on the next attempt

Answer (score 0):

I altered the way I was testing, and I was able to verify the parameters. I essentially used an object to wrap the value to be verified.

```
public class VerifiableObject
{
    public int val;
    public VerifiableObject(int _val)
    {
        this.val = _val;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_MailIt()
    {
        int testMailItem = 0;
        VerifiableObject v = new VerifiableObject(testMailItem);
        
        PostMan p = ReusableMethod(v, null);

        testMailItem = 7;
        v.val = testMailItem;

        PostMan p1 = ReusableMethod(v, p);

    }

    private PostMan ReusableMethod(VerifiableObject testMailItem, PostMan p = null)
    {
        if (p == null)
        {
            Mock<IMyWebSocket> obj = new Mock<IMyWebSocket>();
            obj.Setup(x => x.send(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<int>((x) => { Assert.AreEqual(testMailItem.val, x); });
            p = new PostMan(obj.Object);
        }

        p.MailIt(testMailItem.val);
        return p;
    }
}
```